# Apache Flink - usage of "BuckeingSink" class

Tags: hadoop, hadoop2, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am working on a poc to write to hdfs files using BucketingSink class. Even though the data is being writing to hdfs files, but the files are lying with “.pending” on hdfs.

Below is the code I am using. Can someone pls help me identify the issue and help me fix this ?

```
BucketingSink<String> HdfsSink = new BucketingSink<String>("hdfs://xxxx/xxxx/xxxx/Test/");
HdfsSink.setBucketer(new DateTimeBucketer<String>("yyyy-MM-dd--HHmm"));
HdfsSink.setBatchSize(1024 * 1024 * 2); // this is 2 MB,
HdfsSink.setInactiveBucketCheckInterval(10000L);
HdfsSink.setInactiveBucketThreshold(10000L);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that the actual reason for the files staying as .pending is... because i have not enabled checkpointing. Once i enabled checkpointing... files are closing successfully without lying as .pending.

You can enable checkpointing by setting `env.enableCheckpointing(<duration>)`

Please check url @ https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.html for more details.

Answer (score 0):

**Hi You could use this.**

Hi, unfinished buckets have the .pending extension. Once a bucket is closed (for example for time-bucketing, once the time is over), the file will be renamed. Since you are using the NonRollingBucketer, the files will never be closed. I would recommend you to use the DateTimeBucketer.

As a side note: I would recommend you to increase the checkpointing intervall a bit. 123 milliseconds is very frequent and the application doesn't look like being extremely latency critical. A value like 2000 milliseconds is probably more appropriate.

Comment: Hi, 

Thanks for the response. I found out that the actual reason for the files staying as .pending is... because i have not enabled checkpointing. Once i enabled checkpointing... files are closing successfully without lying as .pending. 

Please check url @ https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.3/api/java/org/apache/flink/streaming/connectors/fs/bucketing/BucketingSink.html for more details.